Error when decrypting a string in Rust using CryptoJs
I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted string using crypto js or AES-GCM as an algorithm, but I run into several problems when I try to decrypt this value in Rust.
JS
const encryptionKey = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef';

const ivKey = 'abcdef9876543210abcdef98';

async function decrypt (data) {
    const keyBuffer = hexStringToArrayBuffer(encryptionKey);
    const ivBuffer = hexStringToArrayBuffer(ivKey);

    const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        keyBuffer,
        { name: 'AES-GCM', length: 256 },
        false,
        ['encrypt']
    );

    const encodedData = new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(data));

    const encrypted = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: 'AES-GCM',
            iv: ivBuffer
        },
        key,
        encodedData
    );

    const encryptedArray = new Uint8Array(encrypted);
    const authTag = encryptedArray.slice(-16);
    const encryptedData = encryptedArray.slice(0, -16);

    return {
        encryptedData: arrayBufferToHexString(encryptedData),
        authTag: arrayBufferToHexString(authTag)
    };
}

function hexStringToArrayBuffer(hexString) {
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(hexString.length / 2);
    for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = parseInt(hexString.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}

function arrayBufferToHexString(buffer) {
    return Array.prototype.map
        .call(new Uint8Array(buffer), (x) => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2))
        .join('');
}

As you can see, I generate an auth tag and an encrypted data and return them. So far everything is ok, I have no problems.
The problem comes when I try to decrypt these values ​​in Russian, hitting the following error:
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/generic-array-0.14.7/src/lib.rs:572:9:
assertion `left == right` failed
  left: 16
 right: 32
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Rust decryption algorithm
use aes_gcm::aead::{Aead, KeyInit};
use aes_gcm::Aes256Gcm;
use hex::decode as hex_decode;
use std::str;
use aes::cipher::generic_array::GenericArray;
pub fn decrypt(encrypted_data: &str, auth_tag: &str) -> String {
    let encryption_key = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
    let iv_key = "abcdef9876543210abcdef98";

    let key = hex_decode(encryption_key).expect("Failed to decode encryption key");
    let iv = hex_decode(iv_key).expect("Failed to decode IV key");
    let mut data = hex_decode(encrypted_data).expect("Failed to decode encrypted data");
    let tag = hex_decode(auth_tag).expect("Failed to decode auth tag");
    data.extend_from_slice(&tag);

    println!("{:?} key {:?}", key, iv);

    let key = GenericArray::from_slice(&key);
    let nonce = GenericArray::from_slice(&iv);
    let cipher = Aes256Gcm::new(key);

    let decrypted_data = cipher
        .decrypt(nonce, data.as_ref())
        .expect("Failed to decrypt data");

    str::from_utf8(&decrypted_data)
        .expect("Failed to convert decrypted data to string")
        .to_string()
}

I understand the error completely but I don't understand mostly where the mistake is. To encrypt or decrypt?
Probably this question will help more people considering that I did not find a similar article or problem on stackoverflow.
I tried all the possibilities from manually performing the decryption functions to another type of encryption and encryption but the same problem.
// Edit
An error log
stack backtrace:
   0:        0x101dd6b05 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h6f224ea69532b9c4
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:104:5
   1:        0x101dd6b05 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h7e173ef23e4514eb
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:        0x101dd6b05 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::hb68789b79179df75
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:68:5
   3:        0x101dd6b05 - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h46bc8e86d021398c
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:44:22
   4:        0x101dfa273 - core::fmt::rt::Argument::fmt::hf606bd67a54daa54
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/core/src/fmt/rt.rs:142:9
   5:        0x101dfa273 - core::fmt::write::h1c24e945c7ef8357
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1120:17
   6:        0x101dd3d0e - std::io::Write::write_fmt::hd9fe01a40900d808
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1846:15
   7:        0x101dd68d9 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h3bfcf7a1dfb9a746
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:47:5
   8:        0x101dd68d9 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::hdbfcabb7d363540a
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:34:9
   9:        0x101dd8295 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::hecb24382dfeeea98
  10:        0x101dd800e - std::panicking::default_hook::h78dca947ab9e89eb
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panicking.rs:292:9
  11:        0x101dd8703 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hb83cee65df04957a
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panicking.rs:781:13
  12:        0x101dd8614 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::hbe6e44d88f82bc77
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panicking.rs:659:13
  13:        0x101dd6ff9 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::h6560cb9c1f1224c1
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:171:18
  14:        0x101dd8356 - rust_begin_unwind
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panicking.rs:647:5
  15:        0x101e24585 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::h2aac8cf45f7ae617
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
  16:        0x101e24a3d - core::panicking::assert_failed_inner::h377f34e690e6e8ab
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/core/src/panicking.rs:342:17
  17:        0x101e0ebd9 - core::panicking::assert_failed::h7c18744966749ff0
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/core/src/panicking.rs:297:5
  18:        0x10103e64c - <&generic_array::GenericArray<T,N> as core::convert::From<&[T]>>::from::h13bb34cdbaf6af27
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/generic-array-0.14.7/src/lib.rs:572:9
  19:        0x10117ef25 - <T as core::convert::Into<U>>::into::h55ae20b055ef3396
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:758:9
  20:        0x10103f15c - generic_array::GenericArray<T,N>::from_slice::h1fd6e9151602a5c2
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/generic-array-0.14.7/src/lib.rs:550:9
  21:        0x101257594 - test_webservices::collector::utils::encryption::decrypt::h2071ee932960bb3e
                               at /Users/dani/Desktop/test/test-webservices/api/src/collector/utils/encryption.rs:19:15
  22:        0x101186d4c - test_webservices::main::{{closure}}::h98a054c1e2023a73
                               at /Users/dani/Desktop/test/test-webservices/api/src/main.rs:41:16
  23:        0x101147a52 - tokio::runtime::park::CachedParkThread::block_on::{{closure}}::h90dcd65894642728
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/park.rs:282:63
  24:        0x1011474e5 - tokio::runtime::coop::with_budget::hbcb1d9a49f27187c
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/coop.rs:107:5
  25:        0x1011474e5 - tokio::runtime::coop::budget::hed56745815abfb38
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/coop.rs:73:5
  26:        0x1011474e5 - tokio::runtime::park::CachedParkThread::block_on::h4d112537feae6908
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/park.rs:282:31
  27:        0x10124b4b0 - tokio::runtime::context::blocking::BlockingRegionGuard::block_on::hf00928678cd4b19a
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/context/blocking.rs:66:9
  28:        0x101120a0f - tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::MultiThread::block_on::{{closure}}::h165886b097094cda
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/scheduler/multi_thread/mod.rs:87:13
  29:        0x1011594ef - tokio::runtime::context::runtime::enter_runtime::hab7765b3fedd824d
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/context/runtime.rs:65:16
  30:        0x1011209aa - tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::MultiThread::block_on::hf723d49b1f52a5cd
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/scheduler/multi_thread/mod.rs:86:9
  31:        0x101159a65 - tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on::h4c943d09a6ac0f51
                               at /Users/dani/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.35.1/src/runtime/runtime.rs:350:45
  32:        0x10104556d - test_webservices::main::h8c308a401db50cb2
                               at /Users/dani/Desktop/test/test-webservices/api/src/main.rs:116:5
  33:        0x10127ff3e - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h8c08f1fcdc25775e
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
  34:        0x1011e4ae1 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h764b8bb33be6af21
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:155:18
  35:        0x1011606a4 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::he71d402513eebe6e
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/rt.rs:166:18
  36:        0x101dcf070 - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::hac29e61381d6586a
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:284:13
  37:        0x101dcf070 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h065989f252650e50
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panicking.rs:554:40
  38:        0x101dcf070 - std::panicking::try::ha0fc5d419bd51724
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panicking.rs:518:19
  39:        0x101dcf070 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h40c50b2f134ab9d1
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panic.rs:142:14
  40:        0x101dcf070 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}::h13332ae052ba6668
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
  41:        0x101dcf070 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h49a2e0d693fc1a69
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panicking.rs:554:40
  42:        0x101dcf070 - std::panicking::try::hf8bc2ebd65d6cdc0
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panicking.rs:518:19
  43:        0x101dcf070 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h695dc526977c6951
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/panic.rs:142:14
  44:        0x101dcf070 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::h963c626e0d7ddd6e
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  45:        0x101160677 - std::rt::lang_start::h5e243eeb95bce71f
                               at /rustc/25ef9e3d85d934b27d9dada2f9dd52b1dc63bb04/library/std/src/rt.rs:165:17
  46:        0x1010455f8 - _main
  47:     0x7ff812e20366 - <unknown>



did you consider you should run with \RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace` - which may help you discover where the assertion failed?

Please edit your question to add the extra information. The stack trace in a comment is unreadable.

If that error trace doesn't help, perhaps it's because Some details are omitted, run with \RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace`

Done. I added the rest.

So what's on line 19, column 15 of encryption.rs?

Seems to me you're encrypting with a 128-bit AES key, but then trying to use it as a 256-bit key in the rust code.
Try with use aes_gcm::Aes128Gcm; instead.
Also, in the js code, your passing a parameter { name: 'AES-GCM', length: 256 }, to importKey but as far as I can tell, there's no such parameter length - and you're still only using a 128-bit key.
